Empty dataframes in jupyterlab
I am not receiving error messages in my current script- but I am being told that as soon as I start dropping any NaN values, all of my dataframes are empty, so there is nothing to graph. Here is my script below
#converting time data to integer values
rawTime= pd.to_datetime(data.iloc[3:, 0], format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
deltaTime = (rawTime-rawTime.iloc[0]).astype(np.int64) /(10e8*60)

#name generation for instruments
names = ["GeoFlex" + str(i) for i in range(1, 51)]

#pulling indexed data- this didnt work- got different shapes from 50 
#tiltX = data.iloc[4:4601, range(5, 122, 4)].set_axis([names], axis="columns")
#tiltY = data.iloc[4:4601, range(6, 123, 4)].set_axis([names], axis="columns")

# Adjusting the range to match the length of `names`
num_sensors = len(names)
tiltX_cols = list(range(5, 5 + 4 * num_sensors, 4))
tiltY_cols = list(range(6, 6 + 4 * num_sensors, 4))

# Determine the end row dynamically
end_row = data.shape[0]

# Pulling indexed data
tiltX = data.iloc[3:end_row, tiltX_cols].set_axis(names[:len(tiltX_cols)], axis="columns")
tiltY = data.iloc[3:end_row, tiltY_cols].set_axis(names[:len(tiltY_cols)], axis="columns")

#removing NaN values without changing index
#tiltXWithoutNaN = tiltX.join(deltaTime).dropna().astype(float)
#tiltYWithoutNaN = tiltY.join(deltaTime).dropna().astype(float)

# Create a DataFrame for deltaTime- this is the area I start receiving empty dataframes
deltaTime_df = pd.DataFrame(deltaTime, index=data.index[3:end_row], columns=['deltaTime'])

# Ensure all columns are numeric
tiltX = tiltX.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
tiltY = tiltY.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# Remove NaN values by interpolation
tiltXWithoutNaN = tiltX.interpolate().dropna().join(deltaTime)
tiltYWithoutNaN = tiltY.interpolate().dropna().join(deltaTime)

# Join with deltaTime ensuring proper alignment
tiltXWithoutNaN = tiltXWithoutNaN.join(deltaTime_df, how='inner')
tiltYWithoutNaN = tiltYWithoutNaN.join(deltaTime_df, how='inner')


Your problem probably lies in your use of the columns=['deltaTime'] parameter. When the input of pd.DataFrame() contains column labels, the columns argument will be used to select the columns in the input data. So, rather than labelling your data, the function is looking for a deltaTime column in data, finding none, and returning all NaNs. You could remove this parameter and rename the column in another step.
